# How to test TCP protocol services?

Tags: testing, network-programming, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a client and his need is to do Load testing for his TCP protocol services. We have some feasibility in JMeter and I have gone through the link; https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter.

What are the best open source tool available in the Market to test manually?
What are the best practices of it?

Comment: This is the prototype of my url which I am trying to test;
net.tcp://xxxx.yyyy.com:808/prod/zzzwebservice.

Can any one help he how to test it? How to send this request and check the response?

Answer (score 1):

Any [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) client or something like [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) or any other tool capable of sending network requests, search for [TCP Client Software](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tcp%20client%20software&oq=tcp%20client%20software) over the Internet.

Why JMeter doesn't fit your requirements?

Comment: Oh. You are in. Happy to hear from you. JMeter is good but I need to cross verify with other tools to test some request manually.